# latin1_bin vs latin1_general_cs in terms of performance

Tags: mysql, database, optimization, collation

I want to make a column case-sensitive in mysql 5.7 for which we have 2 collation options - latin1_bin and latin1_general_cs for latin1 charset.
Is anyone aware which collation be a better approach in terms of search performance. I have an index on this column.

Comment: *which collation be a better approach in terms of search performance.* No difference.

Comment: Use the collation that is appropriate for your data and application; don't worry about performance.